# Amazon AWS IAM user link not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I created an AWS account from Japan. I am new to it and hence operating on free tier account. I am not able to access the IAM user link of my AWS account from any other PC except my own (maybe I can access it on my PC because I haven't cleared it's cache). I get a 'Bad Gateway' error from other systems in Japan and 'Connection refused' error in India when I try accessing the link. The link is of the following nature,

https://AWS-account-ID.signin.aws.amazon.com/console

I also made the inbound traffic of all security groups associated with my VPC and EC2 instance to 0.0.0.0/0.Please help.

Comment: Try pinging the IP of AWS server (not EC2)

Comment: where can i find the IP of AWS server?

Answer (score 0):

The console link is not associated with Security Groups or Amazon EC2 settings.

If you are unable to access the https://AWS-account-ID.signin.aws.amazon.com/console link, then it has something to do with your Internet configuration -- either on your computer, or in the network between you and AWS.

Try accessing the non-IAM console login screen via https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home -- that URL is user-independent and is a good test of network connectivity.

Comment: When i follow this link https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home I get the IAM signin page on my PC and the root login page on every other PC. Why so? I want to get the IAM user signin page on other PC's as well

Comment: Good -- this shows that there is no networking problem. IAM stores a cookie on your browesr, which is why your PC defaults to the IAM sign-in page. The remaining mystery is why `https://123456789012.signin.aws.amazon.com/console` does not work on some machines!